# How do I block league of legends

Tags: firewall, sonicwall

I have an education client that has students accessing the popular game League of Legends and they have requested that we block it on the network. They have some level of BYOD, we are primarily doing their networking support so the plan would be to block their access to the servers (not too concerned about any local play or one player.)

They are currently using a Dell SonicWALL for their firewall/content filter.

I've looked around StackExchange, Google, reddit, and LoL's website, maybe I'm missing something, does anyone know the IP addresses or domains of the game servers? Any other way to block internet access to the game?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you block that on the firewall, then you are going to need to block VPNs, too. Companies which allow BYOD really should outsource that to a company that specializes in it. It is a rather large legal risk that someone does something illegal (scams child pornography, etc.) from a company's network with a BYOD device since the company can often be considered an accomplice. This happens more often than you think, and it gets hushed up and swept under the rug with money.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty standard in most firewall nowadays. The feature you are looking for is "App control" and it's a licensed feature in your Sonicwall Firewall.

I confirm you that you can block "league of legends" packets. Take a look at Sonicwall live demo http://livedemo.sonicwall.com/ES/

Answer (score 0):

With a UTM box, like fortigate or even SonicWall, it's possible to block this type of content and other illegal stuff as well.

I don´t know the SonicWall capabilities but in fortigate we can block applications, like LoL, by their signatures. Can SonicWall do something like this?

Comment: Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time.